# How to concatenate/replace specific words and a values in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column of lists in pandas DataFrame like:

```
column_name_1
{"deltaImp":"10.3-13.1-14.1-15.1"}
{"deltaImp":"10.3-13.2-14.1-15.1"}
```

How can I transform the column values so the result should be:

```
column_name_1
{deltaimp=[{name=10, value=2}, {name=13, value=1}, {name=14, value=1}, {name=15, value=1}]}
{deltaimp=[{name=10, value=2}, {name=13, value=2}, {name=14, value=1}, {name=15, value=1}]}
```

I did try next steps:

```
for key, value in pd.Series(df['cookies(babydriver)'].values).items():
    for key, value in dict.items():
        list = [[int(x) for x in ss.split('.')] for ss in value.split('-')]
```

So I got:

```
[[10, 3], [13, 2], [14, 1], [15, 1]]
```

and here I am stuck trying to add "name=" and "value="

The result of df['column_name_1'].head().to_dict()
the original contains more values in the same format

```
{0: '{"deltaImp":"10.3-13.1-14.1-15.1"}',
 1: '{"deltaImp":"10.3-13.2-14.1-15.1"}'}
```

Comment: What is a "column of lists"? A pandas dataframe?

Comment: Yes, added in description.

Comment: None of your desired results would be valid Python. You seem to be looking for the `dict` type.

Comment: Please read about how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: could you include the output of `df.column_name_1.head().to_dict()` in your question

Comment: Wow, OP has moved the goal posts like 6 times with these edits...

Comment: @onyambu included the result of df.column_name_1.head().to_dict()

Comment: @ddejohn actually just one time, when replaced transitional result of my efforts.. other edits were related to structuring my question

Comment: You can tell that your values are string rather than sets

Comment: @onyambu well my idea was to transform it to the nested list and add words 'name=' and 'value=' to the first and second value in the nested lists. and after that make it sets and add 'deltaImp=' to the start. But failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do it while processing the data the first time:

```py
import ast  # built-in


def transformer(col):
    data = ast.literal_eval(col).get("deltaImp", "")
    result = ", ".join("{{name={}, value={}}}".format(*item.split(".")) for item in data.split("-"))
    return f"{{deltaImp=[{result}]}}"
```

Then:

```py
df["to_DB"] = df["column_name_1"].apply(transformer)
```

Output:

```py
In [4]: df["to_DB"] = df["column_name_1"].apply(transformer)

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
                        column_name_1                                              to_DB
0  {"deltaImp":"10.3-13.1-14.1-15.1"}  {deltaImp=[{name=10, value=3}, {name=13, value...
1  {"deltaImp":"10.3-13.2-14.1-15.1"}  {deltaImp=[{name=10, value=3}, {name=13, value...
```

Comment: Any particular reason you want this data structure? It's not really very useful. What are these values? Why not add new columns to your dataframe and give them meaningful names?

Comment: sadly it is a data structure in db, so on input i am having:
{"deltaImp":"10.3-13.1-14.1-15.1"}

and should replace it with:
{deltaimp=[{name=10, value=2}, {name=13, value=1}, {name=14, value=1}, {name=15, value=1}]} to upload it back to db

Comment: You are my hero, thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help. Make sure to accept an answer so that your question can be removed from the unanswered queue. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df['col2'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: [{'name': x[0], 'value': x[1]} for i in x])
print(df)

# Output
                                   col1                                               col2
0  [[10, 3], [13, 2], [14, 1], [15, 1]]  [{'name': [10, 3], 'value': [13, 2]}, {'name':...
1  [[10, 3], [13, 3], [14, 1], [15, 2]]  [{'name': [10, 3], 'value': [13, 3]}, {'name':...
```

Input data:

```
>>> df
                                   col1
0  [[10, 3], [13, 2], [14, 1], [15, 1]]
1  [[10, 3], [13, 3], [14, 1], [15, 2]]
```

Comment: edited the post. sorry, now wrote the original task

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
df.column_name_1.apply(lambda x: {key:[dict(zip(['name', 'value'], map(int, j.split('.')))) for j in val.split('-')] for key, val in eval(x).items()})
```